# Prototype missing : after element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using this script in prototype

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

$('li.home').setStyle({
  padding-top: '10px'
});

});
```

And it gives me the error

```
missing : after property id
padding-top: '10px'\n
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setStyle uses the camelized version of the css property you wish to set](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#setstyle-class_method). So, `padding-top` should be `paddingTop`.

Also, $() expects the parameter to be a string containing an element's ID, or an element to be extended.

If you'd like to select a number of elements matching a selector, use $$(). Please note $$() returns an array, so you'll have to manipulate each element by enumerating, or using a Enumerable method like [invoke](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable.html#invoke-instance_method) to make a call to each element.

try

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

$$('li.home').invoke("setStyle", {
  paddingTop: '10px'
});

});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. changing this to paddingTop gives me

$("li.home") is null
$('li.home').setStyle({